# Contrapositive of independence --> uncorrelation statement

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence, correlation

So I know that the statement "If two random variables are independent, then the two random variables are uncorrelated" is true.

Does that mean its contraposition "If two random variables are correlated, then the two random variables are dependent." also true?

In terms of the theory of logic, the contrapositive
statement should also be true, but then again, I learned "correlation does not imply causation". So I'm a bit confused.

Can someone clarify this? Is the contrapositive statement really true? If so, what is the difference between that statement and the statement "correlation does not imply causation"??

Comment: Yes, if two random variables are correlated, then the two random variables are dependent.

Comment: The number of cellphones sold is correlated with the number of legos sold.  So, if I sell more cellphones, then that will... *cause*... more legos to be sold?  Obviously not.  Both increase in sales based on the increases in population, the increase in expendable spending, the increase in popularity of these, and so on.  They are still dependent.  If I were to look at a random year, and without looking at the year number I could by looking at the number of cellphones sold estimate the number of legos sold... but to emphasize, that is merely because they are both caused by something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the preferred term is generally "not independent" rather than "dependent" for exactly this reason.  The term "dependent" might make it sound like there is a causal relation between the two random variables, but "independence" just means that knowing one gives no extra information about the other, so "not independent" means that knowing one *does* give some information about the other.